# How to flatten list of lists of dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I created a list of dataframes by grouping them on a certain field. I'm performing an operation that drops specific rows in a specific group. Now, I want to overwrite this specific group with the modified group, and then I want to flatten this list of groups into a dataframe and export it to csv. Basically retracing my steps to before the groupby, minus the rows affected post-condition check. How can I achieve this?

Here's my code:

```
g = x.groupby(x['field1'])
groups = [[field1,df] for field1,df in g]
y = groups[0][1]

# after a certain condition is met for a specific group...
y = y.drop(int(index)) # index is a variable from the condition check and is used to drop that specific index in the df
y = y.reset_index(drop=True)
df = pd.DataFrame()
for ta,group in groups:
    df = group.unstack()
df.to_csv('post_match_{}.csv'.format(session['username']))
```

I tried using pd.concat(groups) also but it didn't work. Keep getting TypeErrors.

Comment: "I tried using pd.concat(groups) also but it didn't work. Keep getting TypeErrors" What, *exactly* did you do and what, *exactly* are the errors you are getting? `pd.concat` is what you would need to use.

Comment: So instead of `group.unstack()`, I changed it to `pd.concat(group)`. Then I got the error: " TypeError: first argument must be an iterable of pandas objects, you passed an object of type "DataFrame" "

Comment: Right, because that isn't how you use `pd.concat`. Indeed, this isn't how you would accumulate a bunch of unstacked `group`'s anyway. All you need is `df = pd.concat(groups)`, no loop.

Comment: Of course, it looks like your code doesn't actually modify any of the data-frames in your `group` list, so that probably won't result in what you want *anyway*, but that's another bug, which likely is due to the same misunderstanding that you had when you did `df = pd.DataFrame()` and then looped over groups, assuming `df = group.unstack()` would somehow accumulate into the empty data-frame.

Comment: After `df = pd.concat(groups)`, returned with the error: " TypeError: cannot concatenate object of type "<class 'list'>"; only pd.Series, pd.DataFrame, and pd.Panel (deprecated) objs are valid "

Comment: Yeah, because `groups` is `[[field1,df] for field1,df in g]`, so you can just do `pd.concat([df for _,df in groups])`

Comment: For that matter, `groups = [[field1,df] for field1,df in g]` is just a convoluted way of saying `groups = list(g)`

Comment: Ok worked. And added in the line `groups[0][1] = y` to update the existing group with the modified group